# E2597 Id: file too small (length=0) for architecture arm64

Tags: ios, xcode, delphi, sdk, paserver

I develop **iOS apps** using **RAD Studio 10** Seattle (Delphi) from a Windows 10 system
Due to the new requirements to submit to the App Store, I have upgrade my Apple environment:

- MacBook Air
- macOS Hight Sierra 10.13.6
- Xcode 10.1
- PAServer 17.0

From that moment, I can not compile my apps, or just a new basic one.
I use the target platform:

**iOS Device - 64 bits - iPhoneOS 12.1.**

The error generated is:

```
  [DCC Error] E2597 Id: file too small (length=0) for architecture arm64
  [DCC Fatal Error] F2588 Linker error code: 1 ($00000001)
```

I would be very grateful if someone would help me.

Comment: AFAIK you will have to upgrade to Rio that has full support for linking against iOS 12.x SDKs.

Comment: iOS 12 support was added in Rio, according to the help file's [What's New](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/What%27s_New#iOS_12_support) topic. That means it's not available in Seattle.